# change rails default application html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the latest rails and I am don't understand how to change the default application.html.erb
and nothing pops up except deleting a file from the public directory. but the only things in there are the error messages and a favicon. Am I supposed to delete it and create my own application.html.erb or am I supposed to modify it. and where is the default html located for the home page? thanks Very new to rails. nothin I do seems to have any effect on it. even changing the title name has no effect

Comment: [Rails guide will help you learning how this works](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 2):

In rails application, its routes.rb file in config/routes.rb which drives the routing and navigation across views.

Adding this line to the file would ensure the application would pickup the html.erb file you want as the root.

```
root :to      => "static#index"
```

p.s delete any existing root references in the routes file.